# How to use Ruby and PIK together with Windows Services?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, thin, win64, pik

I have a Windows server that runs multiple Ruby apps, some requiring different Ruby versions. For managing Ruby versions we use the "PIK" Ruby version manager.

For an app we use Windows Services + SrvAny + Thin to run it. Screenshot of config:

[image]

However, I can't find any documentation on how to change the Ruby version for this specific Windows service. Right now, it just picks the one in the PATH env variable.

Is there a way to change ruby version using pik with Windows system services?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are many ways to do what you want but one that comes to mind is editing `bundle.bat` which is presumably used to launch your service and adding somewhere on the top of the file a `pik` command to specify the version you want to use.

For example:

```
pik use 186 mingw
```

This will switch to the specified version (you can use `pik list` to see the ruby versions available to your system) and execute your service with this version.

See also `pik`'s [usage guide](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik/wiki/Usage) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about that... I'll try it.

Comment: OK, i tried adding PIK to bundle.exe. If I do that the app doesn't run at all, either via CMD.EXE or Windows Services. The first command is with @@C:\bin\pik.bat use 193@@ at the top, the last is without. http://cl.ly/image/1M2e1e3u3z15

Comment: It seems to me that it starts fine and that it's listening for connections. If you want to get rid of the warning regarding Gemfile source, just add this to your project's Gemfile: 
`source "https://rubygems.org"`

Comment: Yes, it ran fine when I removed the PIK command. But it seems it is working if i do ""C:\bin\pik_runner.exe" "C:\bin\pik.bat" use 193" instead of just "C:\bin\pik.bat use 193", apparently the bat file halts execution somehow.

Comment: Nope, service still won't run, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use with pik the follow command (an example using a windows service):

```
pik 193 & rails server
```

**context:**

when the services run, this are using a default ruby installed, for example launch a bar.rb, then bar.rb launch other ruby server like rails server or thin server, but if you launch that with a dos command to open new instance then you can use this 2 command: pik and the desired command